# Using spring HATEOAS with spring webflux Functional Web Framework (reactor-netty)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, spring-webflux

Can we use spring `HATEOAS` on top of `RouterFunction` ? I imagine that we can specify the resource but what will be the equivalent of the `linkto(Controller.class)` ? or is there any equivalent to specify the link and use composition of `RouterFunction`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650753/hateoas-on-spring-flux-mono-response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HATEOAS on Spring Flux/Mono response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650753/hateoas-on-spring-flux-mono-response)

Comment: Here you find the issue for this topic: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/996

Answer (score 1):

By definition, you're creating a custom route and Spring `HATEOAS` is an opinionated set of frameworks meant so you don't have to lift a finger. What you are trying to do, and what Spring `HATEOAS` is doing are contradictory. So, you will have to manually create the payload if you want embedded hyperlinks.

Although, this shouldn't be too difficult if you set your owner content handler for your specific return type on that route.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in January 2023: [not yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/996).

`Spring HATEOAS` was originally built with Spring MVC in mind, so even `WebFluxLinkBuilder` relies on Controller annotations to build the resource links.

The `RouterFunction` interface has no methods that expose the underlying `RequestPredicate`, so there is no way to determine which path is associated with a given `RouterFunction`. Some method may be introduced in a future API to provide the needed access to that information out-of-the-box, without having to do something nasty like breaking encapsulation with `Reflection`. In the meantime, you'd probably need to consider centralizing all relevant `RouterFunction` creation (e.g. via a helper/util/custom builder class), so you can intercept all paths and the associated `HandlerFunctions` with some degree of confidence.

Yeah, when you use `RouterFunctions`, unfortunately `Spring HATEOAS` does not help creating the links, and it is challenging to reliably implement this functionality in a generic way based on the current WebFlux functional API.

Comment: By the way, I eventually managed to do it by implementing my own `LinkBuilder` that uses the `ApplicationContext` to retrieve the `RouterFunction`, as it became clear `Spring HATEOAS` really can't do it out-of-the-box.

Comment: Flavio: Care to share how you did it?