# Return hal+json and json based on client's Accept header

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

In my Spring Boot 2 REST with HATEOAS application, my `/users` endpoint produces `application/hal+json` and my `/users2` endpoint produces `application/json`. I'd prefer to have a single endpoint `/users` which generates two different representations based on the client-defined `Accept` header:

```
# Produce JSON+HAL
curl                                    http://localhost:8080/api/users

# Produce JSON+HAL
curl -H "Accept: application/hal+json"  http://localhost:8080/api/users

# Produce JSON
curl -H "Accept: application/json"      http://localhost:8080/api/users
```

Is there an elegant way with Spring REST?

The two endpoints are current defined as:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public @ResponseBody PagedResources<PersistentEntityResource> pagedUsers(Pageable pageable, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
    return pagedAssembler.toResource(personHandler.users(pageable), assembler);
}

@GetMapping("/users2")
public List<Person> allUsers() {
    return personHandler.allUsers();
}
```

I need the plain JSON (i.e., non-HALed) API because of the (current) [lack of reactive support in Spring HATEOAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650753/hateoas-on-spring-flux-mono-response).

Comment: Have you investigated the `produces` attribute to `RequestMapping`?

Comment: Yes @chrylis -- I've tried various incantations of the `produces` attribute which trigger a 404 -- it seems Spring's routing is not able to differentiate the APIs when negotiating content.